# How to display text looping with different date

Tags: java, substring

So i need to gather data from my db, it's holiday date in my country, the data comes like this.

```
Example 1 : THU     21    May     Ascension Day of Jesus Christ        *ICDX GOLD open fo
Example 2 : MON-THU 28-31 Dec     Substitute for Commemoration of Idul Fitri Festival
```

So i need to get data from dates and the holiday name, for get data from example, i'm using code like this

```
    String ex1= "THU     21    May     Ascension Day of Jesus Christ        *ICDX GOLD open for"; //i don't need *ICDX so i cut it with trim split
    String ex2= "MON-THU 28-31 Dec     Substitute for Commemoration of Idul Fitri Festival       ";//so i cant cut using substring cause holiday name not fixed length
    String curr = ("CURRENCY IDR"); // to display currency code [hardcoded]
    String dateno = (ex1.substring(8, 13)); // to take date number by substring
    String month = (ex1.substring(14, 17)); // to take month name by substring
    String[] splm = dateno.trim().split("   "); // to trim space after date number
    String dat = (splm[0]); //date number display
    String date= (dat+month+"2020");// display date with year ex1 (21May2020)
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy"); //SDF to parse my date format
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"); //SDF to new date format
    String comment= (ex1.substring(18, 77)); //Display holidays name by substring
    String[] spl = comment.trim().split("   ");// Trim comment by spaces, so after 3 spaces its cut, like ex1 i dont need *ICDX
    String comm= ("HOLIDAY NAME " +spl[0] +"\r\n"); //Display holiday name

    System.out.println(curr); //sysout currency name
    Date datef;
            try {
               datef = sdf.parse(date);
            System.out.println("DATE " +sdf1.format(datef)); //sysout formatted date

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            };
      System.out.println(comm); //sysout holiday name
```

and the output come like this

```
CURRENCY IDR
DATE 20200521
HOLIDAY NAME Ascension Day of Jesus Christ
```

The question if i need to do that to example 2 with value date 28 Dec until 31 Dec, and the output must be like example 1,  and look like this

```
CURRENCY IDR
DATE 28122020
HOLIDAY NAME Substitute for Commemoration of Idul Fitri Festival

CURRENCY IDR
DATE 29122020
HOLIDAY NAME Substitute for Commemoration of Idul Fitri Festival

CURRENCY IDR
DATE 30122020
HOLIDAY NAME Substitute for Commemoration of Idul Fitri Festival

CURRENCY IDR
DATE 31122020
HOLIDAY NAME Substitute for Commemoration of Idul Fitri Festival
```

Do anyone have idea what function i have to use to display such output? i'am still new in java, so i take any advice, feel free to comment, thanks

Comment: try with a regex matching

Comment: i'll search how regex matching does, thanks for helping :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kofemann suggested you can use regex. take a look at the following code.
Note that you may want to change the regex as the full context may differ.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        final String dayOfTheWeek = "(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)(-(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun))?";
        final String name = "  (\\w{4})[a-z 0-9]+\\b";
        final String Month = "\\ (Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Sep|Sept|Nov|Feb|Apr|Jun|Aug|Oct|Dec)\\ ";
        final String dateNo = "[\\d]+(-[\\d]+)?";

        final String string = "THU     21    May     Ascension Day of Jesus Christ        *ICDX GOLD open fo\n"
             + "MON-THU 28-31 Dec     Substitute for Commemoration of Idul Fitri Festival";

        final Pattern dayOfTheWeekPat = Pattern.compile(dayOfTheWeek, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        final Pattern namePat = Pattern.compile(name, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        final Pattern monthPat = Pattern.compile(Month, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        final Pattern dateNoPat = Pattern.compile(dateNo, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        final Matcher dayOfTheWeekMatcher = dayOfTheWeekPat.matcher(string);
        final Matcher nameMatcher = namePat.matcher(string);
        final Matcher monthMatcher = monthPat.matcher(string);
        final Matcher dateNoMatcher = dateNoPat.matcher(string);
        String curr = ("CURRENCY IDR"); // to display currency code [hardcoded]
        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy"); //SDF to parse my date format
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"); //SDF to new date format
        Date datef;

        while (dayOfTheWeekMatcher.find()&&nameMatcher.find()&&monthMatcher.find()&&dateNoMatcher.find()) {
            /*
            System.out.println("date of the week: " + dayOfTheWeekMatcher.group(0).trim());
            System.out.println("name : " + nameMatcher.group(0).trim());
            System.out.println("month " + monthMatcher.group(0).trim());
            System.out.println("date no.: " + dateNoMatcher.group(0).trim());
            */
            String comm = ("HOLIDAY NAME " +nameMatcher.group(0).trim()+"\r\n"); 
            System.out.println(curr);
            String date= (dateNoMatcher.group(0).trim().split("-")[0]+monthMatcher.group(0).trim()+"2020");// display date with year ex1 (21May2020)
             try {
               datef = sdf.parse(date);
               System.out.println("DATE " +sdf1.format(datef)); //sysout formatted date

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            };
            System.out.println(comm);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The regex is fine. Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: wow this is brilliant, thanks guys for helping, i manage to solve it by myself, but not with this logic, i want to learn this regex matching logic more, and thanks for giving me example, thanks guys ^^